# Why does switching from AT&T to Intel syntax make this tutorial segfault using GAS?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, gnu-assembler, att

I'm working through some of the tutorials on http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gas-nasm/index.html to familiarize myself with x86/x64.  This tutorial code compiles and runs without a hiccup using the provided code, which uses AT&T syntax:

```
.global main
.text
main:                               # This is called by C library's startup code
    mov     $message, %rdi          # First integer (or pointer) parameter in %edi
    call    puts                    # puts("Hello, World")
    ret                             # Return to C library code
message:
    .asciz "Hello, World"           # asciz puts a 0x00 byte at the end
```

However, when I convert this code to Intel syntax, I get a "Segmentation fault" error.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.global main
.text
main:                               # This is called by C library's startup code
    mov     rdi, message            # First integer (or pointer) parameter in %edi
    call    puts                    # puts("Hello, World")
    ret                             # Return to C library code
message:
    .asciz "Hello, World"           # asciz puts a 0x00 byte at the end
```

I'm not familiar with x86, so perhaps I'm missing something.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you compare the binary outputs?

Comment: @JensBjörnhager, I did not compare the binary outputs.  I'm a novice in assembly, and I know even less binary. Is there something specific I can get from comparing the binaries without being a low-level guru?

Comment: Probably, `mov rdi, offset message` was mentioned?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, changing `mov rdi, message` to `mov rdi, offset message` works.  Would you be able to point me in the right direction as to why this works?  I assume it has something to do with pointing `rdi` to the location in memory right before `message` starts?  Why is an offset necessary in Intel's syntax but not AT&T's?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In AT&T syntax, `mov     $message, %rdi`, the `$` means *immediate*, meaning the address of *message*.

In GAS's Intel syntax, `mov     rdi, message` means absolute addressing, meaning the **content** at *message*. To get the actual address of *message*, you need to supply the `offset` keyword: `mov rdi, offset message`.

Disassebly of the two binaries shows the difference:

AT&T:

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
0:   48 c7 c7 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdi
```

Intel:

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
0:   48 8b 3c 25 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0,%rdi
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Jens! That just clarified a whole lot for me.