# Using ".intel_syntax noprefix" how can I get memory address of a label?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, real-mode, intel-syntax

I'm learning how to create real mode programs assembled and linked with:

- GCC Assembler version 2.25
- Binutils version 2.25
- GCC version 5.2.0

I use Intel syntax without prefixes specified with `.intel_syntax noprefix`

I want to load the address of a string into the *SI* register. I know, how to refer to a memory location in *NASM*, but when I do the same inside the GNU Assembler code, it only moves a WORD of the string into the register instead of the address of the label.

My code is:

```
.code16
.intel_syntax noprefix

mov cx, 11
mov si, name
mov di, 0x7E00
push di
rep cmpsb
pop di
je LOAD
```

When I compile it with GCC, I can see in the debugger that the processor does:

```
mov si, WORD ptr ds:0x7d2d
```

but I want the address of the string moved into the register, not the data it points at.

I also tried to put square brackets around the name like this:

```
.code16
.intel_syntax noprefix

mov cx, 11
mov si, [name]
mov di, 0x7E00
push di
rep cmpsb
pop di
je LOAD
```

It doesn't make a difference.

From *NASM* I know that this assembly code works:

```
mov si, name
```

*NASM* will generate the instruction that moves the address of `name` into register *SI*.

My question: Is there a way to force *GCC* using Intel Syntax with No Prefix to load the address of a symbol into a register?

Comment: After the fact I found a related question, with a [Stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121173/why-does-switching-from-att-to-intel-syntax-make-this-tutorial-segfault-using-g) that is similar . This question might be considered a duplicate depending on perspective.

Comment: I found both questions (and answers) useful separately.  This question _exactly_ described the problem I was having, as I was using direct system calls to Linux to print a string.  The related question addressed a different problem I encountered when using the C standard library to print a string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using GNU assembler code (via *GCC*) with the directive:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
```

Then the syntax can seem a bit unusual, and not well documented in canonical sources. This code:

```
mov si, name
```

Moves the 16-bit *WORD* at memory location pointed to by label `name` into *SI*. The following instructions do the same thing, although I prefer the square brackets `[` and `]` because the code's intent is clearer:

```
mov si, name              
mov si, [name]
mov si, word ptr [name]   # This is the same as two above in long form
                          #     The use of "word ptr" here is similar to MASM
```

To get the address of `name` and place it into the register you need to use `offset` like this:

```
mov si, offset name
```

---

If someone has a **canonical** source that actually describes the syntax that can be used with `.intel_syntax noprefix` please let me know in the comments. I am aware of [blogs about the syntax](http://x86asm.net/articles/what-i-dislike-about-gas/), along with some contempt, but nothing official.

Comment: I haven't seen any open-source projects with `.intel_syntax` source files.  Projects usually choose either AT&T-syntax, or use NASM or YASM.  I can't think of / remember any specific reasons why GNU `.intel_syntax` is less good, though.  e.g. I don't think there's anything you can do in AT&T syntax that you can't in `intel_syntax`, or extra ambiguities.  (The downside for me is that it's like MASM syntax, while I prefer NASM syntax where `[]` is required for all effective addresses.)

Comment: @PeterCordes : I agree, and this syntax is not something I see often - I know of some of the ambiguities, but it is definitely one area that I lack first hand experience with. If I'm using GAS I'll usually settle for AT&T syntax, if I want Intel I'll use NASM, YASM etc. If you are stuck with GAS with no alternative and aren't use to AT&T syntax then I guess that might be a use case here. imagine my disappointment when I couldn't find a canon source for the complete syntax. Reading binutils source is too much like work ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I expected it would be officially documented somewhere, too.  I'm not totally shocked that it doesn't seem to be, though.  For me, it's read-mostly format for disassembly / compiler output, not writing in.